# Problem encrypting data using Java AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding vs. using .NET AesCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: java, .net, encryption, aes

I'm looking for some solutions with trying to encrypt a value using Java 8 AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding vs. using .NET AesCryptoServiceProvider using the same secret key between both implementations.  Should the two methods using the same secret key produce the same encrypted values?

Below is the Java used to encrypt data:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec() {
    if (secretKey != null){
        return secretKey;
    } else {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            byte[] key = masterKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            return secretKey;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException in getSecretKeySpec " , e);
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("UnsupportedEncodingException in getSecretKeySpec " , e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public  String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
    try {
        secretKey = getSecretKeySpec();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
         LOGGER.error("Error while encrypting: " , e);
    }
    return null;
}


Below is the .NET used to encrypt data:

<!-- language: lang-vb -->
Dim key As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(masterKey)
Dim sha As New SHA256Managed()

key = sha.ComputeHash(key)
Array.Resize(key, 16)

'Using the AesCryptoServiceProvider Cryptography Class
_aesCrypto = New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
_aesCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
_aesCrypto.BlockSize = 128
_aesCrypto.KeySize = 128    'KeySize for encryption mode ECB
_aesCrypto.Key = key
_aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

Public Function EncryptAesCrypto(ByVal message As String) As String
    _crypto = _aesCrypto.CreateEncryptor(_aesCrypto.Key, nothing)
    Dim encrypted As Byte() = _crypto.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message).Length)
    _crypto.Dispose()
    
    Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
End Function
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? You are merely saying that you have a problem.

Comment: Both codes derive the key from a password as the first 16 bytes of a SHA256 hash and encrypt with AES in ECB mode (the latter does not require an IV, which makes it insecure). So if the same password and the same message are used, the same ciphertext should result. A bit irritating is that the VB code uses an IV despite the ECB mode, but maybe this is ignored.

Comment: However, in the VB code the key truncation from 32 to 16 bytes does not seem to be done correctly. Take another look at this.

Comment: Yup, and `_aesCrypto.KeySize = 128    'KeySize for encryption mode ECB` doesn't force it to be 128 bit key size; you can still set it to another key size and override. Not sure what use ECB is of course. @Topaco If I'm remembering correctly it is indeed ignored.

Comment: Just tested and as suspected the IV for ECB mode is ignored. Nevertheless it's more consistent to pass `Nothing` as 2nd parameter in `CreateEncryptor()` for ECB mode.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the Java code provided was used to encrypt json formatted data in several thousands of files and I'm trying to convert the Java code into .NET to replicate the encryption, but the encrypted values between the Java code and .NET code are producing different encrypted results.  The same secret key is being used in the .NET approach that was used for the Java method.  Is there something wrong that I'm not seeing with the .NET AES encryption code provided?

Comment: Yes, and I have already pointed it out. In the VB code the key is not correctly truncated from 32 to 16 bytes (the implemented approach does not work). Just debug and then you will see it.

Comment: Problem solved.  Thanks Topaco for the good advice.  I changed the key truncation to use Array.Resize and then used "nothing" as the IV.  These two AES encryption implementations are now producing the same encrypted values.